# Why is ペラペラ written in katakana?

Tags: etymology, katakana, onomatopoeia

I am aware of the meaning of this word, but want to know the reason it is predominantly written in katakana. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many onomatopoeia are written in Katakana (and many in hiragana as well).

Comment: Are there any onomatopia that have kanji alternatives? I can't think of one offhand.